# X does not load amdgpu driver on Debian stretch/testing

Tags: debian, xorg

amdgpu is installed, kernel modules are loaded:

```
# lsmod|grep amdgpu
amdgpu               2031616  0
ttm                    98304  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        163840  1 amdgpu
drm                   372736  3 amdgpu,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
mfd_core               16384  1 amdgpu
```

amdgpu X driver is installed:

```
# dpkg -l|grep amdgpu
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                                             2.4.74-1                                    amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386                                              2.4.74-1                                    i386         Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                                        1.4.0-1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
```

I've even tried to specify to load amdgpu driver in Xorg.conf:

```
# cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "AMDgpu"
    MatchDriver "amdgpu"
    Driver "amdgpu"
```

However it looks like it is not tried to load:

```
# grep LoadModule Xorg.0.log
[    57.973] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    58.107] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    58.154] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[    58.275] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    58.297] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    58.314] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    58.384] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    58.471] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    58.507] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    60.079] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
```

lshw -c video output:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=256) memory:d6100000-d613ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d6000000-d603ffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:d6040000-d605ffff
```

How can this happen?
What to do to force to load amdgpu driver?

Comment: What driver are you using?
Run `lshw -c video` and look for the line "configuration".

Comment: I add this info to the question.

Comment: Still does not work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

adding the `amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.si_support=0` kernel parameter should work with kernel 4.13 or above.

see : [Enable Southern Islands (SI) and Sea Islands (CIK) support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#Enable_Southern_Islands_.28SI.29_and_Sea_Islands_.28CIK.29_support) for detail.

Answer (score 0):

1/ This card `product: Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]` appears to have a TeraScale 3 architecture (see [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_8000_series)), and is not supported by the AMDGPU driver (it is too old). See [this helpful article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU) from the Archlinux wiki.

According to the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Supported_Devices) you should install the [xserver-xorg-video-ati](https://packages.debian.org/xserver-xorg-video-ati) driver wrapper package instead of AMDGPU.

2/ Then there is `product: Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]`.

This card is has a 'GCN 1st gen' architecture, but it seems that it is not supported by the AMDGPU driver (again, see [this helpful article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU) from the Archlinux wiki). The ATI package should provide a driver for it.

Edit: See @susurri's answer: The GCN 1st gen card would be a Southern Island card (that is what they called the Desktop versions anyhow), and could be supported by AMDGPU, meeting certain requirements.

Note that you might have to/ want to install the firmware-amd-graphics or firmware-linux-nonfree package if you encounter and dislike poor 2D/3D support. See that same [article on the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Supported_Devices).